# Lost connection error when trying to connect to proxy SQL on VM with Container Optimised OS

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, database-connection, proxysql

For a project with Data Fusion I need to create a Virtual Machine with Proxy SQL. In order to test this proxy I've created a second instance with MariaBD but I'm not able to establish the connection with the proxy. Here is what I have:

A VM running on Container Optimised OS with a static internal IP and no external IP. This VM is running with the following startup script:

```
sudo docker run -d \
  -p 0.0.0.0:3307:3307 \
  gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:latest /cloud_sql_proxy \
  -instances=sqlinstance_connection_name=tcp:0.0.0.0:3307
```

a Cloud SQL for MySQL instance with private IP activated.

Everything is running on GCP in the same project on the same region and network (default). Firewall are widely open for testing purpose.

When running the following command `mysql -u user_name -p'123' -h 10.132.0.4 -P 3307` from a second VM for testing purpose I have the following error:

```
(HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 11
```

So what is the issue here?

Comment: can you ping one vm from the other ?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: both virtual machines are running on your PC ? why aren't you using docker-compose instead of having the overhead of using Vms?

Comment: Everything is running in GCP. I'm using Vms because I need it in the context of a bigger project involving data fusion

Comment: great, so both servers are in the same network , that means you can use the private ip to ping one from the other

Comment: yes but how do you want me to do it exactly?

Comment: try to use the ping or telnet command from one machine to the other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232711/discussion-between-simon-breton-and-eitank).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the instance's service account has the CloudSQL Client role?